# В подпроекте CMake не находит QT классы

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, cmake

Структура проекта:

```
temp\CMakeLists.txt
temp\main.cpp
temp\testclass\CMakeLists.txt
temp\testclass\testclass.cpp
temp\testclass\testclass.h
```

Не могу понять как нужно делать *CMakeLists.txt* файлы:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
set(MY_PROJECT_NAME temp)
project(${MY_PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Xml LinguistTools REQUIRED)

file(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
file(GLOB CONFIGURATION_FILES rules/*.ini)
file(GLOB UIS *.ui)
add_executable(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${UIS} ${UICS} ${RESOURCES})
include_directories(testclass)
add_subdirectory(testclass)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Xml testclass)
```

**testclass\CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(testclass)              # Название проекта

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Xml LinguistTools REQUIRED)

file(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
file(GLOB CONFIGURATION_FILES rules/*.ini)
file(GLOB UIS *.ui)


add_library(testclass STATIC ${SOURCES})# Создание статической библиотеки
```

Программа максимальна простая:
**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include "testclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(&widget);

    TestClass t;
    QLabel * label = new QLabel(t.getText());
    gridLayout->addWidget(label);

    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**testclass\testclass.h**

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H
#include <QString>
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();
    QString getText();
};
#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

**testclass\testclass.cpp**

```
#include "testclass.h"

TestClass::TestClass() {  }

QString TestClass::getText() { return "TestClass"; }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, если у вас обишка компиляции или линковки - прилагайте ее к вопросу. Это облегчит понимание проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Для имени проекта не нужно указывать отдельную переменную. Когда вы пишите `project(my_project)` автоматически создается переменная `PROJECT_NAME` обращаясь к которой вы получите имя вашего проекта.

2) Не используете `file GLOB` - это вроде бы не плохо, если вы работаете в одиночку над проектом, но даже в этом случае это чревато ошибками. Дело в том, что `cmake` отслеживает файлы, который относятся к компилируемой цели, и если вы в один из них внесете изменения, то этот файл будет перекомпилирован, а проект пересобран. Но в случае с `GLOB` проблема в том, что чтобы пересобрать проект после добавления файла вам нужно очистить кэш `cmake` и пересобрать весь проект. Это терпимо, если вы один, но стоит задействовать еще одно человека и тут же возникнет куча проблем. К тому же сдесь, если мне не изменяет память, вы используете его не совсем верно.

3) Для компиляции, как правило, нужны только `cpp` файлы. Хидеры, ресурсы и прочее - не нужно пихать. Для хидеров устанавливается `target_include_directories` а для ресурсов и `ui` обычно хватает `AUTOUIC` и `AUTORCC` (если они в одной директории с `CMakeLists.txt`

4) Не корректно для верхнеуровневой цели задавать то, что должна предоставить нижнеуровневая цель. Тобишь не нужно указывать `include_directories` для хидеров, которые идут в комплекте с библиотекой. Достаточно просто для вашей библиотеки указать `target_include_directories(my_lib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` и любая цель, к которой будет прилинкована библиотека, будет знать где брать инклюды.

5) Незачем включать повсюды `AUTOUIC` и `AUTORCC` если они вам не нужны

Также порекомендовал бы не использовать дефайны типа `ifndef` - при разростании (и отдаче этого на откуп `QtCreator`) это чревато тем, что в какой-то момент у вас может быть два одинаковых дэфайна. И на это можно убить кучу времени. Лучше используйте `pragma once` - она поддерживается практически всеми компиляторами, кроме одно единственного (названия которого я даже не помню).